# Issue connecting pyodbc to MS SQL database on Windows 10 Pro from WSL2 -> Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyodbc, wsl-2

I have pc with Windows 10. I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2019. Next action, on Windows 10 I installed WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04). **I try to connect from WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04) to MS SQL on Windows 10.**

I have tried everything I know and what I have found. Below are two articles on the subject that I have tried with no success.

I opened the 1433 port in Windows Firewall, and tried use him and not in all options with server and driver. I tried use five options with server and two options with driver, you can see this options in code bellow. I tried edit file /etc/hosts, where I add IP-address 172.29.176.1 (it action describe in second link)

[Connect to SQL Server on Windows from WSL2 with pyodbc - Connection Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68748090/connect-to-sql-server-on-windows-from-wsl2-with-pyodbc-connection-timeout)

[Connect to SQL Server running on Windows host from a WSL 2/Ubuntu sqlcmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939616/connect-to-sql-server-running-on-windows-host-from-a-wsl-2-ubuntu-sqlcmd)

If connect to the MS SQL from Windows everything works.

**What could be the problem, what am I doing wrong, I will be grateful for the help?!**

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import socket

#server1 = f'{socket.gethostname()}.local'
#server2 = 'DESKTOP-2TUPNJK.local'
#server3 = '172.29.176.1' # this is IP-address WSL2 and this IP-address specified in WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04) -> /etc/resolv.conf
#server4 = '192.168.1.4' # this is IP-address my PC on Windows 10
server5 = '127.0.0.1' # this is IP-address from /etc/hosts -> localhost

#driver1 = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
driver2 = '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=' + driver2 + ';SERVER='+server5+';PORT=1433;DATABASE=Test;UID=user;PWD=Password')  
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT name FROM sys.Tables', cnxn)
print(df)
```

I get next error:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue:

First -> the server name must be the IP address of your PC (ipconfig in Windows cmd)

Second -> next step follow this [instruction](https://knowledgebase.apexsql.com/configure-remote-access-connect-remote-sql-server-instance-apexsql-tools/) (I didn't set up -> ApexSQL tools)

And this is my code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1;SERVER=192.168.0.2,1433;DATABASE=Test;UID=sa;PWD=Test')

df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM sys.Tables', cnxn)
print(df)
```